# Share the msg in facebook without going to login page?

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

I am sharing some msg through twitter,Facebook... through Action_Send intent.But what i dont want in this is  that login page.If i click facebook means directly it has to share the msg in my account.Is there any way to give our Login id programmatically so that it will share the msg directly without going to login page?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Facebook Android SDK docs you can save the access token: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/android_sso/#save

But user will have to go through login procedure again when token expires.

It is possible to have a token that does not expire, but AFAIK only in server-side authorization flow: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ (search for `offline_access`).

**Update**

For posting messages to users stream, request the `publish_stream` privilege. See more: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: `offline_access` is an overuse in case when you need only to share messages. `publish_stream` is what you needed to say. "But user will have to go through login procedure again when token expires." --- wrong, it doesn't. All depends on which extended permissions your app has.

Comment: If this is the only case,then how can i do it for other apps like twitter,Gmail or xxxx in the future?

Comment: @Narayanan S: it is API specific. For twitter ask *another* question.

Comment: Is there any permanent solution for this?I am new to android.Pls update me with some code snippets if u have.Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android. Facebook produces access tokens that expire.

Comment: AFAIK Twitter tokens do not expire (currently): https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq